# Come in vs Go in

Tags: difference

I would like to know what the difference between "*come in*" and "*go in*" is. Let's say a little boy, a student, is standing outside the class room and the teacher is in. Then the student say:
- *Teacher may I **come in***.

Why didn't the student just say "*Teacher may I **go in***"?
Also, if the teacher and the student are standing outside the class room, how should the student say to the teacher?

> 1. *Teacher, may I **come in**?*
> 2. *Teacher, may I **go in**?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the teacher is in the classroom, the student would say "Teacher may I come in" because the word 'come' implies the direction toward whom the speaker is speaking to. And, in the other case, when both the teacher and the student are outside, the student should ask "Teacher, may I go in?" because 'go' implies movement away from the speaker
or the person being spoken to.

Here is the reference: http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/confusing_words_come_go.html