# Come vs go - grammar

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Should **go** or **come** be used in this sentence?

Is the answer **come** since the cat is moving towards the people?

> So, Alex decided to organize a meeting with his friends in front of
> the voluntary association. Once there, Alex and his friends went
> inside, hoping to spot the animal. What happened next was amazing! Not
> far from them, a cat started **going / coming** towards them. It was
> him!
>
> That scene filled Alex’s heart with joy. He was so proud of having
> made his friends' day that he came back home with a smile that no one
> could take away from him.

Comment: The narrative is written from the point of view of Alex and his companions, so it's **come**. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239201/come-in-vs-go-in)( and others.

Comment: What Kate said, and to add that it's still correct to use "going", but poor writing style.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the passage is written in [free indirect discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_indirect_speech), i.e., the narrator's perspective can be anywhere in between first- and third-person. So, both **go** and **come** can be used. Which is used depends on which perspective the author has in mind at that moment: *is it more like first-person or more like third-person?*. If first-person, then **come** should be used, if third-person, **go**. The passage doesn't appear to offer a definitive answer.